# Foreign key is empty after saving Hibernate JPA entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here I'm doing a one to many mapping between user and notification tables. After executing the below code, my `userId` column in `Notification` table is empty. Is this the correct way to implementing the mapping?

**User**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "userId")
   private int userId;
    
   @Column(name = "first_name")
   private String firstName;
    
   @Column(name = "last_name")
   private String lastName;
    
   @Column(name = "email")
   private String email;
    
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="user")
   private List<Notifications> notifications;
}
```

**Notification**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "notifications")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Notifications {
    
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "notificationId")
   private int notificationId;
    
   @Column(name = "description")
   private String message;
    
   @Column(name = "is_read")
   private boolean isRead;
    
   @Column(name = "created_at")
   private Date createdAt;
    
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="userId")
   private User user;
}
```

**Saving the data,**

```java
@Autowired
UserRepo userRepository;
    
public String createNotification(int userId,Notifications notification) {
   User user = userRepository
         .findById(userId)
         .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found with id: "+userId));
   user.getNotifications().add(notification);
   this.userRepository.save(user);
   return "Notification added to user successfully";
}
```

NOtification Object:

```
{
   "message":"abc",
   "isRead":"true",
   "createdAt:"2010-06-05"
}
```

Comment: Please show how do you try to save your entities.

Comment: Yeh its updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional):

> Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.

So, you should correct your `createNotification` method in the following way:

```java
public String createNotification(int userId,Notifications notification){
   User user=userRepository
             .findById(userId)
             .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found with id: "+userId));
   
   // sync both side of the association
   user.getNotifications().add(notification);
   notification.setUser(user);

   this.userRepository.save(user);
   return "Notification added to user successfully";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @SternK's answer is correct, I wanna suggest to keep the entities synchronized in the parent entity.
e.g.

```
public class User {
...
public void addNotification(Notification n) {

notifications.add(n);
n.setUser(this);
}
```

Doing this, you do not be worry about keeping the entities synced while you are updating/inserting entities.